# Extending C++ ostream

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm trying to learn more about the workings of the C++ I/O stream library by extending `std::streambuf`.  As a learning experiment, my goal is to simply create a custom stream which directs all output to `std::cerr`.  It seems simple enough:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class my_ostreambuf : public std::streambuf
{
    public:

    protected:

    std::streamsize xsputn(const char * s, std::streamsize n)
    {
        std::cerr << "Redirecting to cerr: " << s << std::endl;
        return n;
    }

};

int main()
{
    my_ostreambuf buf;
    std::ostream os(&buf);
    os << "TEST";
}
```

This seems to work, since it prints `Redirecting to cerr: TEST`.  The problem is that it *doesn't work* when a **single character** (as opposed to a string) is inserted into the stream via `std::ostream::sputc`.  For example:

```
int main()
{
    my_ostreambuf buf;
    std::ostream os(&buf);
    os << "ABC"; // works
    std::string s("TEST");
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(os)); // DOESN'T WORK
}
```

The problem I guess is that `xsputn` doesn't handle single character insertion.  (I guess `sputc` doesn't call `xsputn` internally?)  But, looking over the [list of virtual protected functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/sputc/) in `std::streambuf`, I don't see any function I'm supposed to override that handles single character insertion.

So, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single-character output is handled by `overflow`. Here's how you might implement `overflow` in terms of `xsputn` if `xsputn` does the actual outputting:

```
int_type overflow(int_type c = traits_type::eof())
{
    if (c == traits_type::eof())
        return traits_type::eof();
    else
    {
        char_type ch = traits_type::to_char_type(c);
        return xsputn(&ch, 1) == 1 ? c : traits_type::eof();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is handled by `sputc`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: `sputc` writes a character to the internal buffer maintained by the streambuf. This buffer is flushed when it's full or when the `endl` or `flush` manipulators are used (and in a few other circumstances). When the buffer is flushed, `overflow` is called with the next character that would go into the buffer if it weren't full (or with `eof` if the buffer is being flushed when it's not full). The idea is that `overflow` writes the contents of the buffer, plus the character passed as argument (if not `eof`), to the actual destination. (continued in next comment)

Comment: @0x499602D2: So a functioning streambuf implementation can be written by just overriding `overflow`. `xsputn` is used when outputting a string of characters at once. Its default implementation just writes each character to the internal buffer, as if by `sputc` (where eventually they'll be processed by `overflow`). However, `xsputn` can be overridden do something more efficient, like bypass the buffer and write the string of characters to the destination directly.